# What is the best HTML newsletter builder?

Tags: html, css, web, dreamweaver, newsletter

What is the best HTML newsletter builder?

I have been using Adobe Dreamweaver for years, and I started receiving complicated designs from my client with shadows that can hardly be performed by Dreamweaver.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: hey @Ahmed upvote answer as well please

Comment: hey @smushi .. I was unable to upvote the answer as I am new here. I need 15 reputation. Sorry man!

Comment: @smushi Thanks indeed for your help. I am expert in HTML and usually use notepad++ .. I am wondering, is Microsoft Web Expression the best HTML editor?

Comment: its usually upto a person what they prefer. but most people use CSS/HTML

Comment: What is your favorite editor? :) if i may ask.

Comment: i use text editors such as textmate/text wrangler/notepad++. 

I feel dreamweaver/web expression too limited

Comment: Thanks man! You provided a great help indeed. Excuse me again for not being able to vote for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after drag and drop solution you wont find better than Dreamweaver. There are some others editors out there like

[Microsoft Web Expression](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=36179)

[OpenBexi](http://www.openbexi.com/)

your better off learning HTML/CSS and using editors such as notepad++ and checking in browser.